# Having Trouble Displaying Custom Meta Data on Order Screen

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have the following functions in my `functions.php` to try and pass meta data through to the WooCommerce order page on the dashboard. The problem is I can't get the information to display (see screenshot below).

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_order_item_custom_meta_data', 10, 4 );
function save_order_item_custom_meta_data($item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order) {
  $cart_item = $order->get_item($cart_item_key);
  if (isset($values['custom_data']['shared_owner']) && isset($values['custom_data']['dynamic_amount'])) {
    if (isset($cart_item['entered_width'])) {
      $item->update_meta_data('entered_width', $cart_item['entered_width'], true);
    }
    if (isset($cart_item['entered_height'])) {
      $item->update_meta_data('entered_height', $cart_item['entered_height'], true);
    }
    if (isset($cart_item['square_feet'])) {
      $item->update_meta_data('square_feet', $cart_item['square_feet'], true);
    }
    if (isset($cart_item['num_panels'])) {
      $item->update_meta_data('num_panels', $cart_item['num_panels'], true);
    }
    if (isset($cart_item['product_sku'])) {
      $item->update_meta_data('product_sku', $cart_item['product_sku'], true);    
    }
    if (isset($cart_item['height'])) {
      $item->update_meta_data('_height', $cart_item['height'], true);
    }
    if (isset($cart_item['width'])) {
      $item->update_meta_data('_width', $cart_item['width'], true);
    }
  }
}

add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_key', 'order_item_display_readable_custom_meta_keys', 10, 3 );
function order_item_display_readable_custom_meta_keys($display_key, $meta, $item) {
  if ($item->get_type() === 'line_item') {
    switch ($meta->key) {
      case 'entered_width':
        $display_key = __('Width');
        break;
      case 'entered_height':
        $display_key = __('Height');
        break;
      case 'square_feet':
        $display_key = __('Square Feet');
        break;
      case 'num_panels':
        $display_key = __('Panels');
        break;
      case 'product_sku':
        $display_key = __('Product SKU');
        break;
    }
  }
  
  return $display_key;
}

add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'order_item_headers');
function order_item_headers() {
  echo '<th class="item_meta_heading">' . __('Width') . '</th>';
  echo '<th class="item_meta_heading">' . __('Height') . '</th>';
}

add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'order_item_values', 10, 2);
function order_item_values($product, $item) {
  $width = $item['entered_width'];
  $height = $item['entered_height'];

  if (!empty($width)) {
    echo '<td class="item_meta_value">' . $width . '</td>';
  } else {
    echo '<td class="item_meta_value"> - </td>';
  }

  if (!empty($height)) {
    echo '<td class="item_meta_value">' . $height . '</td>';
  } else {
    echo '<td class="item_meta_value"> - </td>';
  }
}
```

[image: Order without meta data]

I'm not at all sure why this isn't working in the slightest. This meta data is needed to help get information loaded into Salesforce, but if I can't see it, then I can't be sure it's coming through. Some data needs to remain hidden from the customer, but all of it needs to be displayed on the dashboard order page. Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks!